# Entity Metadata Wrapper - check filtered text value is set

Tags: entities

I'm seemingly unable to check for the existence of a value of a field if the field in question is set to filtered text. The following code returns an error - and any possible combination I've tried to find online results in the same:

```
if ($wrapper->__isset('body')) {
  print $wrapper->body->value->value();
}
```

The error:

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unable to get the data property value as the parent data structure is not set. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyValue() (line 438 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/arch-main/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

To be clear, the node does have the body field, but no content has been placed in it.

Any ideas on how to check for this?

EDIT:

Ok this seems to work, but there must be a better way

```
try {
          print $wrap->body->value->value();
        } catch (EntityMetadataWrapperException $e) {
          // ???
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> but there must be a better way

If you find it, do share :)

Seriously though, this is what the language gives you; exception handling is what you should use to handle exceptional circumstances, and an entity not having a field that you're expecting it to have would probably class as exceptional in most people's book. It does in mine anyway.

Comment: The point is, though, that the entity _does_ have the field - just not the value. With any other type of field this would just result in nothing being output, but in the case of filtered text it results in a fatal error. It seems a bit extreme that we have to wrap every filtered text instance in a try/catch instead of the function doing it for us. And shouldn't the __isset function supposed to cover this anyway?